# How can I clear the current search results from meteorhacks:search-source?

Tags: meteor

I'm using meteorhacks:search-source to perform server side searches inside a collection.

In my use case only certain regexes are allowed as search terms.

Here's my scenario:

1. User starts typing a valid search term
2. search-source performs the search and the server returns a number of documents that meet the criteria
3. User types another character that invalidates the regex
4. I don't want to run the search with an invalid search term
5. However the search results that I obtained earlier remain visible

I've tried running a known query that is guaranteed to return no results however then I end up exceeding Meteor's maximum call stack size. (*Literally a stack overflow*)

I see that I can clear the history of the search with .cleanHistory() but that doesn't clear the search *results*.

Sample Code:

```
Template.foo.events({
  'input #myfield': _.throttle(function(ev){
    var str = $('#myfield').val();   
    if ( /[0-9]/.test(str) ) FooSearch.search(str); // FooSearch is a SearchSource object
    // else I want no results shown but I want to avoid a server roundtrip
  },200)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doing a blank search clears it for me:

[image]

Maybe there's something in your `SearchSource.defineSource` causing the overflow?